# Multidimensional Extension of the Wilson Score Method

Tags: multinomial-distribution

Some researchers say that they compared their method with "The natural multidimensional extension of the Wilson score method".

*Chafai, D. and Concordet, D., 2009. Confidence regions for the multinomial parameter with small sample size. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 104(487), pp.1071-1079.*

In **R** there is the function [`MultinomCI()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.40/topics/MultinomCI):

```
MultinomCI(x, method = "wilson"))
```

The binomial [Wilson interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) is:

$$\frac{n_s + \frac{z^2}{2}}{n+z^2} \pm \frac{z}{n+z^2}\sqrt{\frac{n_s n_f}{n}+\frac{z^2}{4}}$$

Is there an equivalent equation for the multinomial Wilson interval, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the same equation for multinominal as it is for binomial.

In Python:

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import statsmodels.api

package_name = "DescTools"

try:
    pkg = importr(package_name)
except:
    ro.r(f'install.packages("{package_name}")')
    pkg = importr(package_name)
pkg

r_string = """CI = MultinomCI(c(11,0,6,11), conf.level=0.95, method="wilson")
"""
ro.r(r_string)
CL = np.array(ro.r['CI'])
print('Multinominal',CL[0][1:3])

low, high = statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint(11, sum([11,0,6,11]), alpha=1-0.95, method='wilson')
print('Binomial    ',[low, high])
```

Gives:

```
Multinominal [0.23565687 0.57590956]
Binomial     [0.2356568654157959, 0.5759095570340281]
```